# Changing the selection in the components page of NSIS based on the OS on which we are installing

Tags: nsis

I am finding it difficult to change the selection in the components page of nsis.
The requirement is during installation i get a license agreement page ,if the user agrees then he/she will click on I AGREE ,after the user clicks on I AGREE ,i want to know on which OS the 
setup is being installed that is it can be either on a Windows Embedded OS or WinXp/Win7.
So if it is Windows Embedded OS i want to change the installation package and if it is not Windows Embedded OS then the installation package will be different.

I am using MUI ver1 not MUI2 in my project.
Please let me know how this can be achieved.

Answer (score 1):

To test for the OS where the setup is running, you can use macros defined `Winver.nsh` with those provided with `LogicLib.nsh` to make elegant tests like this

```
;Dont't forget to include
!include "LogicLib.nsh"                 # use of various logic statements
!include "WinVer.nsh"                   # LogicLib extension for OS tests
```

A platform test example:

```
${if} ${AtLeastWin95}
${AndIf} ${AtMostWinME}
    ;here we are on a pre-win2k
    ;do something        
${elseIf} ${isWin2008}
${orIf} ${AtLeastWin2008R2}
    ;this is post-win7
    ;do other thing
${endif}
```

To change at runtime the components to install, you can use the macros from `Sections.nsh`:

```
;if you have
Section "Sample Database" SecApplicationDB
;...
SectionEnd

;you can select or un select by code:
!insertmacro SelectSection ${SecApplicationDB}
;or
!insertmacro UnselectSection ${SecApplicationDB}
```

Comment: Thanks for your feedback.But here i am able to know on which OS i am installing the setup by reading the Registry entry .My doubt is how to change the install type in the component selection page of nsis

Comment: One solution which i found out is to use section.nsh to select or unselect the checkboxes in components page,in function .onInit.Is that the right solution? I also tried using SetCurInstType but that did not work for me

Comment: @DivyPrakash: yes if you want to change the selected components, yo can use the macros from `sections.nsh`, see my edit

Comment: WinVer.nsh does not currently support the suite mask required to test the embedded bit...

Comment: oops, i missed the embedded part of the question :(

Answer (score 1):

WinVer.nsh does not support checking for Embedded NT but you can perform the check yourself:

```
!include Sections.nsh
!include MUI.nsh

!ifndef VER_SUITE_EMBEDDEDNT
!define VER_SUITE_EMBEDDEDNT 0x00000040
!endif

!insertmacro MUI_PAGE_LICENSE "${__FILE__}"
!insertmacro MUI_PAGE_COMPONENTS
!insertmacro MUI_PAGE_INSTFILES
!insertmacro MUI_LANGUAGE English


Section "Embedded" SID_EMBED
SectionIn RO
SectionEnd

Section "Normal" SID_NORMAL
SectionIn RO
SectionEnd

Function .onInit
System::Call '*(i156,&i152)i.r1'
System::Call 'KERNEL32::GetVersionExA(ir1)'
System::Call '*$1(&i152,&i2.r2)'
System::Free $1
IntOp $2 $2 & ${VER_SUITE_EMBEDDEDNT}
${If} $2 <> 0
    !insertmacro SelectSection ${SID_EMBED}
    !insertmacro UnselectSection ${SID_NORMAL}
${Else}
    !insertmacro UnselectSection ${SID_EMBED}
    !insertmacro SelectSection ${SID_NORMAL}
${EndIf}
FunctionEnd
```